# Get accuracte timestamps when iterating over .wav partials in python

Tags: python, loops, audio, time

I want to make a modification to [Resemblyzer](https://github.com/resemble-ai/Resemblyzer)'s speaker diarization script to cut out parts of audio where a specific speaker isn't present. While the graph generated by the original demo seems alright, the timestamps at which it chooses to cut the audio are off.

I got this conclusion because when I outputted all the timestamp information, my 22 minute long video came out to be 1036 seconds long. Also, the variable I'm indexing the time by seems to be a collection of "`wave partials as a list of slices`", as represented by the function that generates its value. Furthermore, the function I was modifying to get the time said that the intervals were non-reliable.

This is bad, because as you will see below in my code, when cutting the video with ffmpeg, I treat them as if these were one-to-one with the video:

```
from resemblyzer import preprocess_wav, VoiceEncoder
from demo_utils import *
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir, system
from os.path import join



def Diarization(path, file, segments):
    wav_fpath = Path(join(path, file))
    wav = preprocess_wav(wav_fpath)

    speaker_names = ["Peter"]
    speaker_wavs = [wav[int(s[0] * sampling_rate):int(s[1]) * sampling_rate] for s in segments]

    encoder = VoiceEncoder("cpu")
    print("Running the continuous embedding on cpu, this might take a while...")
    _, cont_embeds, wav_splits = encoder.embed_utterance(wav, return_partials=True, rate=16)

    speaker_embeds = [encoder.embed_utterance(speaker_wav) for speaker_wav in speaker_wavs]
    similarity_dict = {name: cont_embeds @ speaker_embed for name, speaker_embed in zip(speaker_names, speaker_embeds)}

    times = [((s.start + s.stop) / 2) / sampling_rate for s in wav_splits]

    keep = True
    cutTimes = [[times[0], times[len(wav_splits) - 1]]]
    #similar = open("similarities.txt", "w+")

    for i in range(len(wav_splits)):

        similarities = [s[i] for s in similarity_dict.values()]
        best = np.argmax(similarities)
        name, similarity = list(similarity_dict.keys())[best], similarities[best]

        #similar.write(f"{times[i]} - {similarity}\n")

        if similarity > 0.65:
            if not keep:
                cutTimes.append([times[i], times[len(wav_splits) - 1]])
                keep = True
        else:
            if keep:
                cutTimes[len(cutTimes) - 1][1] = times[i]
                keep = False

    #similar.close()



    cutCommand = ""
    for num, seg in enumerate(cutTimes):
        if num == 0:
            cutCommand += f"between(t,{seg[0]},{seg[1]})"
            continue
        cutCommand += f"+between(t,{seg[0]},{seg[1]})"

    addMe = "Cut - "
    print(f"ffmpeg -i \"{join(path, file)}\" -af \"aselect='{cutCommand}',asetpts=N/SR/TB\" \"{join(path, addMe+file)}\"")
    system(f"ffmpeg -y -i \"{join(path, file)}\" -af \"aselect='{cutCommand}',asetpts=N/SR/TB\" \"{join(path, addMe+file)}\"")


path = r'C:\Users\mlfre\OneDrive\Desktop\Resemblyzer\Resemblyzer-master\audio_data'

for file in listdir(path):
    #if ".mp3" in file or ".wav" in file or ".mp4" in file:
    if file == "peter.mp3":
        segments = [[12, 21]]
        Diarization(path, file, segments)
```

Since the graph's values were accurate in real time, if I could just manage to get the time intervals accurate in real time as well, I would be golden. Unfortunatley, I do not know how to translate from iterating over a list of wav partials as slices, to the length in time of a wave file.